# Send image using JSON in node.js (express) and an android client

Tags: javascript, android, json, node.js, express

I'm trying to send an image to an android client using node.js, but sending first the URL by a JSON Object which is created by the server. When it tries to set the image, it doesn't work and I don't know why. Inside the folder where I have the file which I apply the node, I have a file which calls Images where I have the image with the name basket.png. When the server serves the JSON, it is recieved by the mobile (as a String) and then it downloads the image by the url (it does the downloading in a class that I called LeerConsulta).

The server code is this one (I wrote  just the part that I consider useful):

```
var express= require('express');
var bodyParser= require('body-parser');
var fs = require('graceful-fs');
var app= express();
app.use(express.static('Images'));
app.post('/Imagen',function(req, res){
    var dir= "http://10.0.0.23:8080/Images/basket.png";
    var obj={"img":dir};
    res.json(obj);
});
```

Here is where I download the image:

```
static String content="", data="";

    public LeerConsulta(String Content, String Dat)
    {
        content=Content;
        data=Dat;
    }
protected Bitmap getBitMap()
    {
        try{
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(content);
            String src=jsonResponse.getString(data);
            java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.connect();
            InputStream input=con.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Finally, here is where I display the image:

```
public class Accedido extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imagen;
    Button ok;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_accedido);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        imagen=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Img);
        ok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Bitmap img=null;
                Ajax im=new Ajax();
                try {
                    String imagen = im.execute(MainActivity.IP_ADDRESS + "Imagen").get();
                    LeerConsulta lec = new LeerConsulta(imagen, "img");
                    img = lec.getBitMap();
                }
                catch(Exception exc) {
                    Toast.makeText(Accedido.this, exc.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                imagen.setImageBitmap(img);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: The `dir` variable points to your server's file system and in the phone it points to phone's file system, this won't work unless the file is already in the phone. So change the `dir` to `dir="http://your server.com/Images/basket.png"`

Comment: I have just done it (like you can read in the edition I made recently) but it still doesn't work. Originally the imageView is white and when I press the button ok it doesn't have anything...At least I have resolved a problem in that case

Comment: It must be because it sends me null because there must be an exception when I'm trying to download it. But  `printStackTrace();` doesn't show it...how can I read it?

Comment: So when you type the URL `http://10.0.0.23:8080/Images/basket.png` in your browser's address bar do you get the image? If yes then that's all I can help you with since I don't know anything about Java or android programming. Sorry.

Comment: When I wrote it in the notebook's browser, appears a message which says `Cannot GET /Images/basket.png`